# How to disable context menu for HTML5 YouTube iframe video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, youtube

I am embedding a YouTube video and manipulating it with the JS API, however I wish to deactivate the context menu that YouTube provides on the video because it causes some glitches in my application.

I am using oncontextmenu="return false;" but it does not seem to work, the menu is always displayed even if I disable the context menu in the page body.

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/yQ5U8suTUw0?autoplay=1&controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen oncontextmenu="return false;"></iframe>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g0g4npty/

Answer (score -2):

I would create an additional html file with embedded youtube video. And in this html file, I would use jQuery to block context menu:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('video').bind('contextmenu',function() { return false; });
});
```

And put this created page to the `iframe` to show the video.